# Converting an array of strings to an array of dateTimes

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

Beginner javascript learner here, trying to convert an array of strings to an array of dateTimes using just vanilla.

Sample input:

```
   ["2018-07-16T14:28:03.123", 
    "2018-07-20T14:00:27.123", 
    "2018-07-26T13:31:12.123", 
    "2018-08-12T13:03:37.123", 
    "2018-09-24T12:35:46.123"]
```

Wanted output:

```
[2018-07-16T14:28:03.123, 
 2018-07-20T14:00:27.123, 
 2018-07-26T13:31:12.123, 
 2018-08-12T13:03:37.123, 
 2018-09-24T12:35:46.123]
```

My string values are always dateTime string representations, so I've been trying to leverage `new Date(stringDateTime)` to convert each string to it's dateTime counterpart, but I'm running into trouble on how to navigate the array and build a new one with the appropriate dateTime data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function:

```
var datesStr = ["2018-07-16T14:28:03.123", "2018-07-20T14:00:27.123", "2018-07-26T13:31:12.123", "2018-08-12T13:03:37.123", "2018-09-24T12:35:46.123"]
var dates = datesStr.map(d => new Date(d));
```

Comment: How would you write the dates variable without the arrow function shorthand?

Comment: `datesStr.map(function(d) { return new Date(d)})`

Answer (score 0):

While Igal's answer is more elegant and concise, I would try to show a more basic solution where you use a for loop and new Date():

```js
var stringDates = ["2018-07-16T14:28:03.123", 
    "2018-07-20T14:00:27.123", 
    "2018-07-26T13:31:12.123", 
    "2018-08-12T13:03:37.123", 
    "2018-09-24T12:35:46.123"];

var dateObjects = [];

//Loop over your string array and push dates in your dateObjects array
for (var index in stringDates) {
  var stringDate = stringDates[index];
  dateObjects.push(new Date(stringDate));
}
```